# React native drawer navigation with I18nManager.forceRTL isn't working

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Been trying to implement @react-navigation/drawer with @react-navigation/native-stack and forcing the app to be RTL, using Expo.

**App.tsx:**

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-view'
import {useLoading} from '@hooks'

I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
I18nManager.allowRTL(true)

export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useLoading()

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider style={{flex:1}}>
        <Navigation />
        <StatusBar style="dark" />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

**Navigation.tsx:**

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackNavigationOptions } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<RootDrawerParamList>()

function RootNavigator() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{presentation: 'modal',  headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={DrawerNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Customer" component={CustomerScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='Customers' screenOptions={{headerRight: Logout}}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{title: Lang.Navigation.Home}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Customers" component={CustomersScreen} options={{title: Lang.Navigation.Customers}} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </View>
  )
}

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
"expo": "~44.0.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
```

The result i'm getting when clicking on the menu built-in hamburger is that the screen does become grayish but the menu never pops in. Using inspect I found that there is a problem with the menu's "left" and "translateX" settings automatically given by the react navigation plugin.

Everything works well when removing the 'ForceRTL' part, but I need the app the be RTL.

Comment: can you create a minimum  reproducable code here https://snack.expo.dev/@hufan/expo-typescript and share link

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@lishar/a7e63f pretty sure it will not run.. but you can generally see the code

Comment: I think the issue is happening  due version of `@react-navigation/drawer` library try after downgrade version to `^5.10.6` here is sample working demo  https://snack.expo.dev/PIIGNx70v

Comment: You actually answered without answering :) The solution was to remove the "forceRTL" stuff and use "direction:'rtl'" IN THE TOP LEVEL COMPONENT instead. It works now without downgrading

Comment: great, let me write answer for future reference

Comment: Wait. marginEnd and Start does not perform as RTL, but as LTR. Please check this: https://snack.expo.dev/@lishar/2a6f24

Comment: have you tried using `direction:'rtl'` in container/element style ?  not able to run on snack right now

Comment: Default text alignment Depends on the text content. you might want to use `flexDirection:'row-reverse'` if it is not working. check  these examples https://codesandbox.io/s/llj0r4jo9z

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the following code.

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
I18nManager.allowRTL(true)
```

fix for this issue is to use `direction:'rtl'` in the style of Root level component. sample working code demo https://snack.expo.dev/PIIGNx70v

sample code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={navigation.openDrawer} title="Open drawer" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, direction: 'rtl' }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerPosition="right" initialRouteName="Home">
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```